# read all parameters of an revit family document

Tags: parameters, autodesk-forge, revit

i have a question about reading parameters of an revit family over autodesk forge. Is it possible to read them directly from forge without converting it, or is it required to use an design automation script to do that?

Answer (score 0):

All standard properties that appear in the property panel in the standard Revit user interface are translated into Forge and made available in the Forge viewer. They are accessible right out of the box with no need for design automation.

Comment: Thank your Jeremy, but for a single .rfa file too? I want to parse per program every rfa file in a folder on BIM360 to list all parameters from these files.

Comment: I do not believe that the Forge environment provides any support at all for RFA files. You could insert a family instance into an RVT and grab the parameter data from that.